# Replacing `for` loop with `forEach` loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm working on StateService methods which move task card to next column. I was able to write `taskMoveLeft` method which works just fine, but I can't duplicate its functionality for `taskMoveRight` method using `forEach` loop, I could get it working only with `for` loop.

Working example of `taskMoveLeft` method (using `forEach`):

```js
taskMoveLeft(id) {
  state.columns.forEach((column, columnIndex) => {
    if (state.columns[0] !== column) {
      if (column.cards) {
        column.cards.forEach((card, cardIndex) => {
          if (card.id === id) {
            if (state.columns[columnIndex - 1].cards) {
              // Add card to the target column card collection
              state.columns[columnIndex - 1].cards.push(card);
            } else {
              // Create target column card collection and add card
              state.columns[columnIndex - 1].cards = Array.of();
              state.columns[columnIndex - 1].cards.push(card);
            }
            // Remove the card from the source column card collecion
            state.columns[columnIndex].cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Working example of `taskMoveRight` method (using `for` loop):

```
taskMoveRight(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < state.columns.length; i++) {
    if (state.columns[state.columns.length - 1] !== state.columns[i]) {
      if (state.columns[i].cards) {
        for (let j = 0; j < state.columns[i].cards.length; j++) {
          if (state.columns[i].cards[j].id === id) {
            if (state.columns[i + 1].cards) {
              // Add card to the target column card collection
              state.columns[i + 1].cards.push(state.columns[i].cards[j]);
            } else {
              // Create target column card collection and add card
              state.columns[i + 1].cards = Array.of();
              state.columns[i + 1].cards.push(state.columns[i].cards[j]);
            }
            // Remove the card from the source column card collecion
            return state.columns[i].cards.splice(j, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can't make `taskMoveRight` method work with `forEach` loop. With this code the card always moves to the furthest right column:

```
taskMoveRight(id) {
  state.columns.forEach((column, columnIndex) => {
    if (state.columns[state.columns.length - 1] !== column) {
      if (column.cards) {
        column.cards.forEach((card, cardIndex) => {
          if (card.id === id) {
            // Create target column card collection
            if (!state.columns[columnIndex + 1].cards) {
              state.columns[columnIndex + 1].cards = Array.of();
            }
            // Add card to the target column card collection
            state.columns[columnIndex + 1].cards.push(card);
            // Remove the card from the source column card collecion
            state.columns[columnIndex].cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why have you A) Inverted the `if` condition, and B) Removed the `else`?

Comment: Also note that the `for` loop you're trying to replace ends early in some circumstances. You can't terminate a `forEach` sequence early. If you need to terminate a `forEach`-like thing early, use `some` (or `every`) or probably, in this case, `find`, instead.

Comment: Or `findIndex`, actually.

Comment: Side note: `Array.of();` is a very odd way to write `[]`. :-)

Comment: > Why have you A) Inverted the if condition, and B) Removed the else?

 I have inverted it cause it's less code and the logic stays the same

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` isn't the right tool there, because you terminate the loop early. Instead, since you need the index of the card, use `findIndex`. See `***` comments for that and other suggestions:

```
taskMoveRight(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < state.columns.length; i++) {
    // *** Instead of repeating it all over
    const column = state.columns[i];
    if (state.columns[state.columns.length - 1] !== column) {
      if (column.cards) {
        // *** Find the card
        const cardIndex = column.cards.findIndex(card => card.id == id);
        // *** Get the card if found
        const card = cardIndex !== -1 && column.cards[cardIndex];
        if (card) {
            // *** Instead of repeating it
            const nextColumn = state.columns[i + 1];
            if (nextColumn.cards) {
              // Add card to the target column card collection
              nextColumn.cards.push(card);
            } else {
              // Create target column card collection and add card
              // *** Using Array.of() to create an empty array and then pushing
              // *** to it is quite round-about; instead: [card]
              nextColumn.cards = [card];
            }
            // Remove the card from the source column card collecion
            return column.cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well if its working for taskMoveLeft(), it's propably right tool for that

Comment: Yes, it's working fine with `taskMoveLeft`, the question is how to reverse direction and use it for `taskMoveRight`

Comment: Please help me to realize it with `forEach` method

Comment: @Jake11 - No, if you look at `taskMoveLeft`, you'll see it keeps looping when it shouldn't -- it's already found the card. Not the right tool.

Comment: @Bong2000 - Why do you want to keep using the wrong tool for the job? The above should move the column right if the previous implementation did. If not, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the code in place so solutions can be tested against it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You most likely right that it's a wrong tool, but for now, I'm more interested in the question why I can't duplicate the same login from moveTaskLeft. 
I will be really appreciated if you can show me how it will look with `forEach` loop.

Thanks for point out on the right tool!

Answer (score 0):

Cause you modify the next row with the current cards, then those cards get moved again when you reach the next row. You have to iterate reversed, so instead of `.forEach((entry, i)` you have to do:

```
  array.reverse().forEach((entry, i) => {
    i = array.length - 1 - i;
```

but thats a bit ugly.

---

Instead I woupd not stick to `.forEach` but rather use a for loop. I would keep an array of entries to move to the right, that way you can reduce the logic to:

```
  let previousMove = [];

  for(const column of state.columns) {
    if(!column.cards) column.cards = [];
    let currentMove = column.cards.filter(card => card.id === id);
    column.cards = column.cards.filter(card => card.id !== id).concat(previousMove);
    previousMove = currentMove;
  }
```

That could also be done with `reduce`:

```
 state.columns.reduce((move, column) => {
    if(!column.cards) column.cards = [];
    const nextMove= coumn.cards.filter(card => card.id === id);
   column.cards = column.cards.filter(card => card.id !== id).concat(move);
   return nextMove;
 }, []);
```

To moveLeft, just use `reduceRight` instead of `reduce`.